# Log4Net using RollingFileAppender combining attribute in logdata and todays date

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm setting upp Log4Net with configurations in web.config and want create text logs `(RollingLogFileAppender)` based on a property in the data combined with todays date. (This was able in code earlier but was a bit ugly so moving everything to web.config):

Something like this `BOOKINGS_20160405.txt`.

So if the data (a dictionary with key/values) which I want to log have a key  called Source: `BOOKING`, I want the result above. This Source can contain several other categories, and should be saved into those log file.

I tried several approaches with `datePattern` but cannot find any solution.

Is this even possible without writing some code for it?
Maybe I should not use RollingLogFileAppender at all for this?

Maybe I can create a custom appended making what I want?

Comment: This definitely sounds like something you want to do in code. Bear in mind that a given appender can only write to one file at a time, so if you have multiple log files and concurrent writes you will have to either use locking or - better - one appender per file.

Answer (score 1):

So I was not able to solve it by pure `<log4net>-configuration`. What I wanted to achieve was maximum configurable appenders, where I did not have to change code and recompile on changes.

But, I went with the code anyway to get it to work.
Maybe it helps someone else.
Looked something like this:

```
public class FileAppender : IAppender
    {
        public void RegisterLogger(ILoggerRepository repository, IConfig config)
        {
            if (!config.isActive) return;
            if (repository.GetAppenders().Any(x => x.Name.Equals(config.logName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) return;

            if (config.path.EndsWith(@"\") == false)
                path += @"\";

            var rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                Name = config.logName,
                AppendToFile = true,
                File = config.path,
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date,
                StaticLogFileName = false,
                DatePattern = $"'{config.logName}_'yyyyMMdd'.log'",
                LockingModel = new log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
                Layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date %-5[%level] - %message%newline"),
            };

            var filters = new List<log4net.Filter.IFilter>() {
                new log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter() { LoggerToMatch = config.logName, AcceptOnMatch = true },
                new log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter(),
            };

            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                filter.ActivateOptions();
                rollingFileAppender.AddFilter(filter);
            }

            rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(rollingFileAppender);
        }

        public void Write(IConfig config, LogData data)
        {
            if (!config.isActive) return;
            var textLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(config.logName);
            var text = $"{data.Sender} - {data.Ip} - {data.Locator} - {data.Text} - {data.Args}";
            textLogger.Info(text);
        }
}
```